# A PHP regex to extract php functions from code files

Tags: php, regex, function, static-analysis

I'm trying to make a PHP regex to extract functions from php source code. Until now i used a recursive regex to extract everything between {} but then it also matches stuff like if statements. When i use something like:

```
preg_match_all("/(function .*\(.*\))({([^{}]+|(?R))*})/", $data, $matches);
```

It doesn't work when there is more than 1 function in the file (probably because it uses the 'function' part in the recursiveness too).

Is there any way to do this?

Example file:

```
<?php
if($useless)
{
  echo "i don't want this";
}

function bla($wut)
{
  echo "i do want this";
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider this: `$s = 'foo function() bar';` and `/* no function() */` and think about the fact that stuff like `/*` can also be placed inside string literals (and vice versa). In short: don't do this using regex (see stereofrog's answer).

Comment: As an alternative to regular expressions (which can never correctly handle all edge cases, this answer explains how to use a PHP parser written in PHP to extract a function from a piece of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907961/101087

Answer (score 6, accepted):

regexps is the wrong way to do it. Consider [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) or [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Answer (score 5):

Moved here from duplicate question: [PHP, Regex and new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971871/php-regex-and-new-lines)

Regex solution:

```
$regex = '~
  function                 #function keyword
  \s+                      #any number of whitespaces 
  (?P<function_name>.*?)   #function name itself
  \s*                      #optional white spaces
  (?P<parameters>\(.*?\))  #function parameters
  \s*                      #optional white spaces
  (?P<body>\{.*?\})        #body of a function
~six';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

P.S.
As was suggested above tokenizer is preferable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

*Regex accepting recursive curly brackets in body*

I know there is a selected answer, but in case tokenizer can not be used this is a simple regex to extract function (name, param and body) from php code.

Main difference with Ioseb answer above is that this regex accepts cases with recursive curly brackets in the body, means that it won't stop after the first curly brackets closing.

```
/function\s+(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)\s*(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})/
```

**Explanation**

```
/                                   # delimiter
function                            # function keyword
\s+                                 # at least one whitespace
(?<name>\w+)                        # function name (a word) => group "name"
\s*                                 # optional whitespace(s)
\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)                # function parameters => group "param"
\s*                                 # optional whitespace(s)
(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})   # body function (recursive curly brackets allowed)  => group "body"
/                                   # delimiter
```

**Example**

```
$data = '
    <?php 
    function my_function($param){
        if($param === true){
            // This is true
        }else if($param === false){
            // This is false
        }else{
            // This is not
        }
    }
    ?>
';

preg_match_all("/function\s+(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)\s*(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})/", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches['body']);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => {
        if($param === true){
            // This is true
        }else if($param === false){
            // This is false
        }else{
            // This is not
        }
    }
)
*/
```

**Limitation**

Curly brackets have to be balanced.
ie, this body will be partially extracted :

```
function my_function(){
    echo "A curly bracket : }";
    echo "Another curly bracket : {";
}

/*
Array
(
    [0] => {
    echo "A curly bracket : }
)
*/
```